# node.js http.get() makes the request without sending the hostname

Tags: http, node.js

I have some node.js code that looks like this:

```
Updater.prototype.poll= function(callback) {
var options = {
    host: api_host,
    port: 80,
    path: update_path,
    method: 'GET',
    agent: false, 
    headers: [{'accept-encoding': '*;q=1,gzip=0'}]
};

console.log('Polling');
var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
    //other stuff here...
});
```

};

The problem is that when the request is sent, the server returns `400 Bad Request - Invalid Hostname`. I've sniffed the TCP stream with wireshark and it seems to not be sending the `Host` part of the http request, but instead generating a line that looks like: `undefined: undefined` . I'm sure the `api_host` variable is set correctly (I've even tried with a hardcoded string). I have also tried using `hostname` instead of `host` . Is there a known reason it might act this way ?

Comment: Also what's the value of options?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's try the sample in the [node.js docs](http://docs.nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) page. Does that work for you at all? What if you replace the host here?

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/index.html'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Secondly, have you looked at using [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)? It's as good a standard module for doing this sort of thing with a much friendlier syntax (similar to jQuery).

Comment: Finally it was a pb in my way of defining the headers (when I changed it from the array notation `headers: [...]` to object notation `headers: {...}` it got fixed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be confirming a bug I also encountered with the new style of creating an http request. From what I've tested, I'm pretty sure that it has to do with setting the content type in the http header / options.

I went back to the old way (ie http.createClient()) and that works. So that's what I'd recommend